# search and return array with subarray in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello community in Laravel I am doing a search, an array listing returns me, it's perfect. I want to return a subarray with a list, how is it done with select? using db :: table in laravel

```
DB::table("campania_post AS pt")
                ->join("campania AS c","c.id","=","pt.campania_id")
                ->where("c.manager_id", "=", $user->id)
                ->leftJoin("files AS f","f.id","=","c.avatar")
                ->where("pt.status", "=", 0)
                ->select("c.id", "c.nombre", "c.avatar", "f.name", "c.created_at", 'f.id as file_picture')
                ->groupby("c.id")
                ->get();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### For Query Builder:

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to a string. And then use `map` on the result to convert it to array.

```php
$data = DB::table("campania_post AS pt")
                ->join("campania AS c","c.id","=","pt.campania_id")
                ->where("c.manager_id", "=", $user->id)
                ->leftJoin("files AS f","f.id","=","c.avatar")
                ->where("pt.status", "=", 0)
                ->select("c.id", "c.nombre", "c.avatar", "f.name", "c.created_at", DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(f.id, ',') AS file_picture"))
                ->groupby("c.id")
                ->distinct()
                ->get();

$data->map(function($q) {
    $q->file_picture = explode(',', $q->file_picture);
    return $q;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, use ->distinct()

Answer (score 0):

```
$data->map(function ($singleData) {
$singleData['img'] = ['Add your sub array'];
return $singleData; });
```

That's all.